# How to Calculate the average of an Existing list inside Knowledge base of prolog code?

Tags: prolog

I have been trying for instance to have a list `[1,3]` and calculate its average inside the code without inputing the least itself. I'm not sure of the correct syntax to make it work, only the first line has a problem since it works perfectly fine if I called average and input the numbers when I run prolog.

```
average([1,3],X).


average(List, Result) :- sum1(List, Len), sum(List, Sum), Result is Sum / Len.

sum([], 0).

sum([H|T], Sum) :- sum(T, Temp), Sum is Temp + H.


sum1([],0).

sum1([_|B],L):-sum1(B,Ln), L is Ln+1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't want to input list all the time. It means, that you should have predicate something like `my_list/1` and use it in your program.

```
my_list( [1,3] ).

average_easy( List, Avg ) :-
    sum_( List, Sum ),
    length_( List, Length ),
    Avg is Sum / Length.

sum_( [], 0 ).
sum_( [H|T], Sum ) :-
    sum_( T, Temp ),
    Sum is Temp + H.

length_( [], 0 ).
length_( [_|B], L ):-
    length_( B, Ln ),
    L is Ln+1.

main :-
    my_list( X ),
    average_easy( X, Ans ),
    writeln((X, Ans)).
```

So, what we've got now, is

```
?- [your_program_name].
% your_program_name compiled 0.00 sec, 64 bytes
true.

?- main.
[1,3],2
true.
```

Btw, there are [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.27%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/builtinlist.html%27%29%29) predicate, already built-in in swi-prolog.

Answer (score 1):

```
avglist(L1,Avg):-sum(L1,0,S),length(L1,0,L),Avg is S/L.

sum([H|T],A,S):-A1 is A+H,sum(T,A1,S).
sum([],A,A).

length([H|T],A,L):-A1 is A+1,length(T,A1,L).
length([],A,A).
```

this is a simple method to calculate the average of a list in swi prolog

Comment: Could you add a little more details about your solution?

Comment: initially A value is 0 which then gradually adds up the values which are in the list and when there are no more values in the list then S takes the value of A.Similarly length/3 calculates the number of elements in the list  where A1 increments its values and passes on to A on each recursion.at last when there is no more element then L takes the value of L.Average is simply sum/lemgth.

Answer (score 0):

You must walk through the list, use 2 accumulators, one for the sum, one for the length and when the walk is finished compute the average.

```
  % here the list is not finished
 walk([H|T], AccTT, AccL, Average) :-
     % here you write the code 
     ..................... 
     % next step
     walk(T, NewAccTT, NewAccL, Average).

  % here the list is finished
 walk([], AccTT, AccL, Average) :-
     % here you compute the average         .
     Average is ....
```